# Efficient way to find position of beacon image in a screenshot

Tags: java, opencv, screenshot, javacv, image-recognition

I have a screenshot taken from `java.awt.Robot` as a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` and know there will be a unique 10x10 solid red (same RGB) coloured square *somewhere* in that screenshot (more likely closer to the middle).

What's an efficient approach to finding its coordinates? Is JavaCV even the right library to use? I found a brute force approach in .net here: [Bitmap Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987811/bitmap-detection) but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is, what does it take to recognize the color - is it an exact RGB value, where either the color is an exact match, or it isn't?  And will that still be the case if the image is lossy-compressed, for example as a JPEG?

Assuming you can do that, probably you want to do a search that tries to minimize time spent searching areas which won't be fruitful:  On an imaginary line between two opposite corners, test the value at each corner and the midpoint;  if no match, try at the midpoint between the midpoints and the corners;  if no match, divide the space in half vertically or horizontally and try again;  once you find a pixel of the right color, have some code that walks the pixels in each direction to determine if it's really 10x10.

Really any sort of search pattern will work;  what you probably don't want is a situation where you just start at 0,0 and go 0,1 0,2 ... 1,0 1,2 since that will make matching in the upper left fast and bottom right slow (assuming a coordinate space that starts at the top left).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I guess OpenCV is too heavy for this problem and more suited to approximate matching.